# What is a quick and dirty way to implement a PayPal discount code for buttons stored at PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I want to implement a solution that isn't too involved without the use of shopping carts.

I have detailed a solution in my own answer to this question, but would love if anyone could suggest a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I actually recently had to do this. My solution was "dirty" and "quick" without a doubt.

Basically, I created 2 separate HTML pages that were almost identical except for one had price options that were discounted and a message that said "Successful discount code!"

Then, you create a front page to those 2 purchase pages. This page asks them to enter a discount code. Example code below:

```
 <form action="check-their-discount-code.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Enter discount code below: <input type="text" name="Discount-code" >
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Then a VERY simple PHP script:

```
<?php
     // Collect Information from form
 $discount_code = $_POST['Discount-code'];

     // See if the Discount Code is correct

 if($discount_code === "DISCOUNT_CODE") { 
     // Code is correct, redirect to discount page!! Yay!

 header("Location: ../page-with-discounted-prices.html");
} else {
     // Code is incorrect, redirect them to non-discounted page

 header("Location: ../page-with-regular-prices.html");
}
?>
```

That is the quickest, dirtiest way to do it in my opinion! It worked just fine.

*NOTE* With this method the pages are not actually protected in any way, so if your customer discovers the Discounted Page's URL then they can easily buy the item at a discount. However, in my case, this did not happen. Also, users cannot look into PHP files so you are safe from anyone discovering your discount code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a form with the following:

```
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="dcode" value="Discount Code">Discount Code</td></tr><tr><td>

<input type="text" name="dcode2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
```

And form action redirecting to a PHP form.

```
 <form name =form action="register2.php" class="emailform" method="post" style ="" onsubmit="return verify()" >
```

In my code verify() is a JS function that returns if the form is valid or not, but the most basic code that you need is simply

```
<form name =form action="yourphp.php" method="post">
```

Then in your PHP form do the following. Paste the button code from PayPal

It should be something like this:

```
     <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin-left:30px;">
 <input type="hidden" name="discount_" value="medium"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="some value">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Not create as many PayPal buttons as needed, with whatever parameters. You have 2 options - set the price of the buttons as required - OR set the extra variables :
discount_amount, discount_amount2, discount_rate, discount_rate2 and discount_num as required in the box on PayPal that asks you to enter extra variables.

Now instead of the line

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="some value">
```

Have the following PHP

```
<?php
$dcode=$_POST["dcode2"];
if ($dcode === "discount code 1") {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hosted_button_id\" value=\"hosted button value 1\">\n";
} 
else if ($dcode === "discount code 2") {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hosted_button_id\" value=\"hosted button value 2\">\n";
} 
else {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hosted_button_id\" value=\"hosted button value 3\">\n";
}
?>
```

Now this is probably, no - definitely a terrible way to do it, but one that I could hack up in a few minutes; especially because PayPal lets me create similar buttons easily.

How would you do it.

Let me know.

Thanks